# Combining stones into one stack

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

At the table there are $n$ stones. At the beginning, each stone lies alone, making it $n$ stacks of 1 stone each.

Julia would like to combine all these stones into one, $n$-element stack. She can do this in $n-1$ moves, and each move consists of combining two stacks together into one. Each time when she combines a stack of $a$ stones with stack of $b$ stones, she gets $a\cdot b$ points.

What's the maximum number of points she can get? **Any hints?**

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:**

The cases $n=1,2,3$ are trivial: we get $0,1,3$ points, respectively. When $n=4$, there are two choices for combining the stacks, both of which give $6$ points. Is there a pattern? Next try $n=5$.

**Hint 2:**

Consider any two stones. How many times will they be put together from separate stacks to form a new stack?

Comment: Is it $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$?

Comment: @MightyPython Yes, no matter how you combine the stacks. Why is that? (Can you find some object that also involves $\frac{n(n-1)}2$ and make a connection?)