# Prove that the sum of numbers written on the board is always equal to $\binom{20}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics

We write the number $20$ as the sum of two numbers $a,b$ and write $ab$ on the board where $a,b \ge 1$. We do this again for $a,b$ until we get only (multiple instances of) the number $1$. Prove that the sum of numbers written on the board is always equal to $\binom{20}{2}$.

I don't know how should I work to get a combination; it is more likely to get a sum?

Comment: Hint: consider the complete graph on $20$ vertices. (That is, take $20$ points and draw lines between every pair of points.)

Comment: @Théophile Ok that is the ways of drawing lines between $20$ points but how is it related to the question?

Comment: The process is not clearly described, which makes it difficult to reason about it. I suppose the following describes it a bit better: form a (rooted) binary tree with its nodes labelled by positive integers, every internal node having two children and label equal to the sum of the labels of its two children, every leaf node labelled $1$, and the root node labelled $20$; show the sum over internal nodes of the _product_ of the labels of its two children equals $\binom{20}2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on the hint I left in the comments:

Consider a complete graph on $20$ vertices. We know that the graph has $20 \choose 2$ edges; we will count the edges a different way. Separate the graph into two disjoint subgraphs $A,B$ of order $a$ and $b$ (so $a+b=20$). There are $ab$ edges in total between $A$ and $B$. Now continue the process on $A$ and $B$. In the end, we will have counted every edge once, so the sum of the products $ab$ must be $20 \choose 2$.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202810/combining-stones-into-one-stack/2202835#2202835), which is the same problem but in the opposite direction.

Comment: Really like this answer ... $n=2$ right?

Comment: @N.Shales Oh, thanks for catching that! It should be  $20 \choose 2$, of course.

Comment: Thought so, just checking. Great insight in this answer btw!

Answer (score 1):

Generalise and prove by induction. For any node labelled $n$ the sum of products over its subtree should be $\binom n2$. This is true for leaf nodes (the sum being empty and $\binom12=0$), and assuming it for children labelled $a,b$, the total sum becomes $\binom a2+\binom b2+ab$. It is not hard to show this is $\binom{a+b}2$. In fact the set of pairs that can be formed from $a$ white balls and $b$ black balls contains $\binom a2$ white pairs, $\binom b2$ black pairs, and $ab$ mixed colour pairs. Or attach triangles of $\binom a2$ and $\binom b2$ points respectively to two sides of a $a\times b$ rectangular array of points, to get a triangular array with $a+b$ points along any side; this for those more visually oriented.

Answer (score 1):

This process can be described as follows:

$F(n) = a \cdot (n-a) + F(a) + F(n-a)$ where $F(0) = F(1) = 0$.

(In other words, given some $n$, we're choosing a value for $a$ and letting $b=n-a$, so that $a+b=n$)

Try with $a=1$:

$F(n) = 1 \cdot (n - 1) + F(1) + F(n-1) = n - 1 + F(n-1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

This at least gives us an easy way to compute $F(n)$ assuming we always choose $a=1$.

Let's try again using induction, with the hypothesis that $F(n) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ is true regardless of $a$ by substituting:

$F(n) = a \cdot (n-a) + \frac{a(a-1)}{2} + \frac{(n-a)(n-a-1)}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

All the $a$-terms cancel out, so $F(n)$ does not depend on $a$. It will always be equal to $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \binom{n}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite a lovely problem.

Intuitively, the problem initially seems quite tricky, or, at least, it did to me.

Starting with the natural number $n$ we split it into two others $a+b$, then take the product $ab$ and iterate this process of spitting $a$ and $b$ multiplying etc. Eventually summing all pairs of products.

In order to gain some intuition for this process I figured that we need some way of coping with both $a+b$ and $ab$ together. The simplest way to do this is to square $n$:

$$n^2=(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$

We have the sum $a+b$ on the left (albeit squared) and the product $ab$ on the right. 
Then, iterating this process: Each of $a$ and $b$ can be written as sums of natural numbers themselves, say $a=c+d$ and $b=e+f$, then expanding

$$n^2=c^2+d^2 + e^2 + f^2 + 2(cd+ab+ef)$$

and so on until we reach

$$n^2=\underbrace{1^2+1^2+\cdots +1^2}_{\text{$n$ times}} + 2S$$

where $S$ is the desired sum of all products.

It should be clear that there will always be $n$ $1^2$ terms:

> To picture this imagine $n^2$ as the area of a square of side $n$. At each iteration we split along the horizontal and vertical of smaller and smaller squares that lie along the diagonal. Eventually we are left with the $n$ leading diagonal $1\times 1$ squares, each of area $1^2$.

So

$$n^2=n+2S$$

therefore

$$S=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\binom{n}{2}$$